# Is it correct to say “Success Attracts The Best“

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say “Success Attracts The Best“ ? I mean, is it a must to add a noun after ‘The Best’ and ‘The’ before Success?

Comment: Seems fine to me. It wouldn't make sense to add "The" before "Success".

Comment: It is grammatical, but whether it is correct in any other sense of the word is a different question entirely. Might as well roll with "verisimilitude attracts giraffes". What does that even mean. And once we've established what it's supposed to mean, is it actually at all true.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Just want to use this phrase as a motto/slogan

Comment: You mean like all the leeches that come out of the woodwork when they find out you’ve got money??